# Override primefaces css with a custom one

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

i made a custom style sheet named `mycustomstyle.css` to override the style sheet provided by primefaces, i placed the link to my style sheet inside the `<h:body>` so that it overrides the one provided by primefaces, but when i see the generated HTML i found that `mycustomstyle.css`  appears before the style sheet of primefaces which means that it didn't override it, this is the generated HTML:

```
<head><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Gambak/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Gambak/javax.faces.resource/css/mycustomstyle.css.jsf" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Gambak/javax.faces.resource/primefaces.css.jsf?ln=primefaces" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Gambak/javax.faces.resource/keyboard/keyboard.css.jsf?ln=primefaces" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Gambak/javax.faces.resource/fileupload/fileupload.css.jsf?ln=primefaces" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="RES_NOT_FOUND" />
```

regarding this order which style sheet overrides the other one? i think that myStyleSheet have been overriden,

my jsf oage code to place the customStyleSheet:

```
<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/template/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">
    <h:body>
        <f:facet name="last">
            <h:outputStylesheet name="css/mycustomstyle.css" />
        </f:facet>
    </h:body>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: Have you excluded the templating from being the cause? I.e., it also fails when putting everything in a single file? If so, please post that file instead as SSCCE. By the way, the body does not support any facets, get rid of it.

Comment: Try to <ui:insert name="head"></ui:insert> inside the h:head for templating and then write your "f:facet with last" in head defination

Answer (score 0):

If you want to override primefaces.css, you can do it by creating blank resouces/primefaces/primefaces.css . It's not perfect but working with Primefaces 5.0